# Looking for a short anime about a blue lizard/alien transformation

Tags: story-identification, anime

It was about a guy with a bandana and brown longer hair (I think) who was very sweet and caring, and he had the ability to transform into a blue fish/lizard like alien thing. He had to fight basically the government soldiers. They were in all black and kind of cybernetic. His rival had blonde hair and was going through that obvious is the person I’m hunting actually bad complex.
Was only like maybe 6 episodes long

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you first see this? Did you see it on TV, physical media, or online? And was the main character aquatic or amphibious in his other form, or did he mostly/exclusively operate on land?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it could be *[Baoh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baoh)*

> 17-year-old Ikuro Hashizawa is kidnapped and turned into a Baoh, a bioweapon with superhuman strength and other abilities, by the Doress Laboratory. He escapes with the help of Sumire, a 9-year-old psychic girl. Professor Kasuminome, head scientist at Doress, sends various assassins and monsters to try and kill Ikuro, in means of stopping the Baoh virus from spreading and infecting the world.

### Image of Baoh transformation

[image: Image of Baoh transformation]

### OVA